# Command-line satellite tracking software

Tags: satellites, software, gpredict

Is there any software similar to [Gpredict](http://gpredict.oz9aec.net/) but which can be used without a GUI and can control rotor Az/EL and radio doppler shift? I'm using Linux in particular, especially Ubuntu 14.04.

Currently, I can control rotors and radio via Gpredict's interface, but it requires manually selecting the satellite and tracking it. I want to script this process — provide [TLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-line_element_set) files and satellite to track and automatically record the downlink (mainly CW beacons) so that I can track multiple satellites without issuing manual commands for each one.

Basically, I'm looking for a command-line interface to Gpredict.

Comment: Adding the OS where you're plan to run the application might be useful to people who want to answer your question.

Comment: @sessyargc.jpk added

Comment: Over the years I have been porting Predict for Linux to Android. I am currently working on adding the Easycom protocol using the IOIO board so you can track satellites and control the rotor from your phone. It's a work in progress but I'm keen to make it more useful for others.

Answer (score 3):

[Predict](http://www.qsl.net/kd2bd/predict.html) is the option that comes to mind. It is console based (no GUI), and provides a *server mode* where you can request data via UDP messages to a running predict server.

It uses hamlib for rotor control.

N.B.: predict *does not* provide transceiver control. You can get the current Doppler (normalized to 100MHz) via UDP queries, so you will need some extra scripting to control your transceiver having this information. I'm personally trying this out.

Predict is very stable (I've had an instance running for months).

You can install it directly from your package manager.

Comment: Agreed. Gpredict started as a PREDICT client.